# Как пополнять контент на bootstrap шаблоне?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, cms

Имеется обычный шаблон `bootstrap` с использованием `html/css/js`. Нужно по типу `CMS` пополнять раздел новости с сохранением дизайна сайта. Натягивать на какие то движки пробовал, но там много лишних функций, да и не все движки позволяют натягивать обычную верстку. Искал бесплатные решения, но ничего не нашел.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: Причем тут задача если я лишь прошу сообщество подсказать какие либо решения. "укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности" - "Нужно по типу CMS пополнять раздел новости с сохранением дизайна сайта"

Comment: потому что вы написали для нас задачу. Именно поэтому вам ещё не ответили. Тут действует правило ->правильный вопрос - правильный ответ.

Comment: Не стоит придираться к стилю написания вопроса. Кто знает, тот поймет.

Comment: `CMS: Content Management System (система управления содержимым)`

Answer (score 0):

Тут 2 решения:

1. Добавлять новые новости вручную, то есть вставлять куски кода(новой новости) на страницу и сохранять.
2. Создать простой движок самому, например, на php.

Comment: Вручную добавлять становится муторно, а про самописные движки хотел узнать по больше. Сам не обладаю опытом программирования на php, может есть какие то примеры или готовые решения?

Comment: Ну это только изучать php с азов - курсов полно в просторах интернета в свободном доступе, как платных, так и бесплатных. Попробуйте http://theory.phphtml.net/